# Allow user to choose how they receive forgot password code

Tags: amazon-cognito

Tried searching for this in Amazon's docs but couldn't come up with anything.

Assuming that both email and phone number are checked in the verification section of the user pool. If the client app wants to allow the user to choose how they receive the code (assuming they've forgotten their password) - how do we get Cognito to handle that? Is there a way of getting the forgotPassword method to select a route (email or SMS)?

From some early testing, it seems like it always goes one route if both are available. I do see that Amazon themselves have made this available on their site though, so *hoping* that it should be possible?

For this example, we can assume that we've got a verified email address and phone number for that user.

Answer (score -1):

I am on the Cognito team. Currently the behavior is that if both phone number and email are verified, the code goes to the phone, hence phone number is given preference and there is no way to select where the code actually goes. However, we have heard this request in the past and I will add a +1 to the feature request on your behalf.